# openssl sslv3 handshake failure

Tags: macos, ssl, openssl, tcpdump, tshark

I run following cmd against calendarserver from my Macbook

```
openssl s_client -host example.com -port 8443
```

I get following output

> CONNECTED(00000003) 42905:error:14077410:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake
>   failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.40.1/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:593:

Can you please tell me:

```
1) What does this error mean?
2) How can I find the ssl version used on the client side and server side?
3) Little explanation will help.
```

Comment: Also see [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830) on the Apple Stack Exchange and [How does SSL/TLS work?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/20803) on the InfoSec Stack Exchange.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).